# htaccess redirect all pages ending with .html to without html Except some pages

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm having an issue with my `.htaccess` rules for redirection.

I need to redirect pages ending with `.html` to the pages ending with slash.
`/about-us.html` to `/about-us/`

But there are also pages where I need to redirect to specific page without `.html` like 
`/gallery/first-gallery/this-is-the-gallery.html` to `/gallery/new/`

The problem is that my rules are not working together nicely, it seems that the rule to redirect .html pages ignores all other rules.

This is how my `.htaccess` looks like

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*).(html)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
Redirect 301 /about-us/photo-gallery/17577-album-mca-corona-clay-tile-roof-princeton-texas/131173-58e29f485064eprinceton-texas-roofing-services-1.html /about-us/photo-gallery/17577-album-mca-corona-clay-tile-roof-princeton-texas/
Redirect 301 /about-us/photo-gallery/17577-album-mca-corona-clay-tile-roof-princeton-texas/131174-58e2a063b8b06princeton-texas-roofing-services-2.html /about-us/photo-gallery/17577-album-mca-corona-clay-tile-roof-princeton-texas/
#Many other 301 rules below
</IfModule>
```

So when I type in
 `domain.com/about-us/photo-gallery/17577-album-mca-corona-clay-tile-roof-princeton-texas/131173-58e29f485064eprinceton-texas-roofing-services-1.html` 
in the browser it redirects to 
`domain.com/about-us/photo-gallery/17577-album-mca-corona-clay-tile-roof-princeton-texas/131173-58e29f485064eprinceton-texas-roofing-services-1`
 where I need this specific redirect to redirect to 
`/about-us/photo-gallery/17577-album-mca-corona-clay-tile-roof-princeton-texas/`

I tried moving the `RewriteRule ^/?(.*).(html)$ /$1 [R=301,L]` to the bottom hoping that the rules above will process first, but that did not work.

What can I do to make this work as I need it?

Answer (score 0):

First of all if there are `mod_alias` like `redirect` and `mod_rewrite` like `RewriteRule` `mod_rewrite` rules get executed before `mod_alias` rules.

There are many senarios to sove this issue like excluding all other redirect rules from the main rewriterule but it think if the other rules `redirect` have same target to only ommit last part of URI you could make rules like the folwoing :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^\/]+)/([^\/]+)/([^\/]+)/([^\/]+)\.(html)$ /$1/$2/$3 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(html)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Rules above will check if `URI` is coming in this form `/something/something/something/something.html` like `/about-us/photo-gallery/17577-album-mca-corona-clay-tile-roof-princeton-texas/131173-58e29f485064eprinceton-texas-roofing-services-1.html` then redirect it into `/something/something/something` and if not coming in this way , the second rule will be applied.

**Note:** clear browser cache then test